# How to calculate associated Legendre polynomials given m and l in Python

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

The general expression for associated legendre polynomial is given as :

[image: for a given m and l]

I have been looking for a python solution, where given m=0 , I can compute the expression for the polynomial of 'Pl' at the given angle theta. For better expressing my question, here's the screenshot from Wikipedia's page on [Associated Legendre Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials) [image]

and so I would need to calculate the values of those P's corresponding to superscript = 0 for a given theta.

I have extensively checked stackoverflow, but failed to find a proper answer, also I have found the python page [with Numpy's Legendre module details](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.legendre.html) but can't find the exact thing I am looking for.

Comment: Are you asking some good samaritan to write the code for you? O_o

Comment: No sorry, I didn't mean that definitely....but if someone can point me to the proper direction I will be obliged

Comment: a pointer... look into scipy (interpolate?) maybe? Otherwise, roll up your sleeves, and start coding; if you have difficulties, post your code, and ask for help, that's what stackoverflow does.

Comment: Thank you, just to politely ask, is it you who downvoted the question? sorry ...I can delete it, if it violated the standards....it's just been that I am stuck here for few days ....

Comment: I think youre in a bit of a tough position because numpy definitely supports similar methods but it takes niche knowledge to be able to advise you on this. I'm not sure you violated any standards here but it might help if you can edit an attempt and show where it goes wrong (or highlight why the closest numpy method doesn't work and what's missing).

Comment: You don't have to delete your question; it is in fact an interesting one, but you need to make it more specific and give the people willing to help you, something to work on.

Comment: Generally, looking for special functions in NumPy is looking in a wrong place; those and similar things are what SciPy is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scipy has the associated legendre polynoms:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.lpmv.html#scipy.special.lpmv

Comment: Thanks, this saved my life, I am however half way into writing my own code of first computing the Legendre polynomial and then from their computing the associated Legendre polynomial. But i will stop now :)

Comment: Just so that you all know, once I finish this analysis, all of your names and the help of this community will be present in my acknowledgement section of the paper that i will publish.